# Should I ask for WINE support here or at askUbuntu?

Tags: discussion

If I have technical issues running steam games through WINE, would it be more appropriate to ask for technical help here or at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)?

Comment: I don't see a problem asking on either, it's on topic here for being about games (precisely `Game-specific hardware and utilities`) and on askbuntu also being about Wine, but you probably will get better help on [askbuntu](http://askbuntu.com) or even [superuser](http://superuser.com/). Technical stuff isn't the strongest part of Arqade.

Comment: We don't have a problem with DOSBOX so I don't see any reason to discriminate against WINE. That said, I'd still suggest asking on [ubuntu.se]. As Jonathan said, our ability to answer technical questions is variable at best. =P

Comment: Keep it focused enough and it won't be an issue. but remember that you may find more experienced help at WINE's forums. Devil's Advocate: Some times its a conf issue that we can see given the logs and errors, other times it should be made aware to WINE's Team. Also I suggest PlayOnLinux or if you're the spendy type, there's always CrossOver (Professional Support from the WINE team).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use your judgement. We are primarily a community of gamers. Ask Ubuntu is a community of Ubuntu enthusiasts. There's also a [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Given your question, which group would you go to for help?

Chances are it should be fairly obvious, but here's some guidelines. Think about where you're getting stuck and decide:

Is your problem with configuration of Linux/a linux tool? Is your problem to do with Ubuntu specifically? Can you run Steam/the game, but there's problems with it?

Where is your error message/problem arising? Hopefully this should help you work out where to ask.

Comment: Depending on his distro, will depend on where he does go.  I wouldnt have him ask here.

Comment: If it makes any difference, I'm on Ubuntu 15.4.

Comment: Any of those communities would love if you check the [Wine Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/) before hand to discard the obvious problems.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem it doesn't. Your question would be about wine, whenever it's running on Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora or Arch it will still be Wine.